# How to record a request in mobile Android using jmeter

Tags: android, jmeter, performance-testing

I am getting below error in Android when connected to jmeter with proxy
How to resolve this issue

**Java. Security. Cert.certpath validatorException:trustAnchor for certification path not found**

Can anyone suggest a tool for Android open source

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Install JMeter's certificate onto your Android device, the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. If your Android version is [7.0 or above](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Nougat) you will need to take some extra steps to wit:

   - add the next line to the [`application`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element) tag of your app [manifest](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro):

     ```
     android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
     ```
   - create `network_security_config.xml` file to your app [resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) folder with the following content:

     ```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
     <network-security-config>
       <debug-overrides>
         <trust-anchors>
           <!-- Trust user added CAs while debuggable only -->
           <certificates src="user" />
         </trust-anchors>
       </debug-overrides>
     </network-security-config>
     ```
   - re-build your app in [debug mode](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/building-cmdline#DebugMode)
   - replace the installed app with the debug version
   - your should be able to record now

More information:

- **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of [JMeter User Manual](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html)
- [Recording Using Android Devices](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000285357-Recording-Using-Android-Devices-Recording-Using-Android-Devices)

Comment: Even though I did above mentioned step still I am getting same issue